# Configuring Conky to report disk quota usage

Tags: debian, conky, quota

Recently I learned how to set up per-user quotas on Debian, and now I'd like to add some quota information to Conky. I've read up a bit on the .conkyrc config, but I'm really struggling with the format.

In my system each user can easily get information about quota by using the "quota" command (or quota -s for human readable) but I'd like to have it shown in Conky as well, in this (or similiar) way:

```
Quota:            800M / 5G
[|||||                    ]
```

I'm not sure how to achieve this, especially how to create such a bar clearly displaying disk quota usage. Any help will be appreciated.